# Исключение при попытке сериализовать коллекцию

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xamarin.forms

В `Visual Studio` создал проект `Xamarin.Forms` под `Android`.
Внутри проекта создаю класс `Person` с несколькими `string` полями.
Далее, создал метод, который должен сериализовать `ObservableCollection<Person>` на носитель:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> _Person;

public Command SaveCommand { get; }

public void Serialize()
{
    _Person = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    _Person.Add(new Person() { Abdomen = "90", Ankles = "10" });
    
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>));
    
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("client.xml"))
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, _Person);
    }
}
```

При запуске отладки на устройстве, я жму кнопку которая должна сохранить коллекцию и получаю исключение:

```
There was an error reflecting type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1
```

Вероятнее всего, сериализация в `Android` происходит как-то по другому, потому как если я помещаю этот код в консольное приложение, то всё работает хорошо и я получаю файл сразу после запуска консоли.

Дополнение 1:
Если подключить `using System.Text.Json;` и сохранять данные в `json`, то всё сериализуется хорошо.

Comment: Вместо `ObservableCollection` используйте `List`. PS: такие коллекции, как ObservableCollection и BindingList предназначены для привязки к GUI.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Исключение будет выбрасываться в любом случае. Дополнил шапку.

Comment: Гм... А какой модификатор доступа у класса `Person`? `public`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне помогла расстановка атрибутов.